# Amazon Elastic MapReduce: Output directory

Tags: hadoop, amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, elastic-map-reduce

I'm running through Amazon's example of running Elastic MapReduce and keep getting hit with the following error:

> Error launching job , Output path already exists.

Here is the command to run the job that I am using:

```
C:\ruby\elastic-mapreduce-cli>ruby elastic-mapreduce --create --stream \
     --mapper  s3://elasticmapreduce/samples/wordcount/wordSplitter.py \
     --input   s3://elasticmapreduce/samples/wordcount/input \
     --output  [A path to a bucket you own on Amazon S3, such as, s3n://myawsbucket] \
     --reducer aggregate
```

[Here is where the example comes from here](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/ElasticMapReduce/latest/GettingStartedGuide/CreateJobFlowStreaming.html)

I'm following Amazon'd directions for the output directory.  The bucket name is `s3n://mp.maptester321mark/`.  I've looked through all their suggestions for problems on [this url](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/ElasticMapReduce/latest/DeveloperGuide/thingstocheck.html)

Here is my `credentials.json` info:

```
{
"access_id": "1234123412",
"private_key": "1234123412",
"keypair": "markkeypair",
"key-pair-file": "C:/Ruby/elastic-mapreduce-cli/markkeypair",
"log_uri": "s3n://mp-mapreduce/",
"region": "us-west-2"
}
```

Comment: why oh why must S3 force us to create a new directory each time?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

hadoop jobs won't clobber directories that already exist. You just need to run:

```
hadoop fs -rmr <output_dir>
```

before your job ot just use the AWS console to remove the directory.

Comment: I've removed the directory before starting the job but it still throws this error.

Comment: Were you able to verify it was actually removed?

Comment: try a different output directory

Comment: Paul, yes, I verified that it was removed.  I've tried removing the directory and re-running.  I've also tried using a new directory name (so it will be created as part of the process).

Comment: weird. is it possible you have a step that runs before the elastic-mapreduce command that is creating the directory before your job starts? Are you literally specifying "s3n://mp.maptester321mark/" as the output directory? If so, you might want to specify a folder like "s3n://mp.maptester321mark/output".

Answer (score 4):

Use:

```
--output s3n://mp.maptester321mark/output
```

instead of:

```
--output s3n://mp.maptester321mark/
```

I suppose EMR makes the output bucket before running and that means you'll already have your output directory / if you specify `--output s3n://mp.maptester321mark/` and that might be the reason why you get this error.

Answer (score 0):

---> If the folder (bucket) already exists then remove it.

---> If you delete it and you still get the above error make sure your output is like this
s3n://some_bucket_name/your_output_bucket    if you have it like this s3n://your_output_bucket/ 
its an issue with EMR!! as i think it first creates bucket on the path (some_bucket_name) and then tries to create the (your_output_bucket).

Thanks
Hari